# Codify a character to binary with BinaryTree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

My idea is to convert a character to binary. For example, 'f' would be '100'. To try this example, in the code below I create that extended binary tree:

[image: BinaryTree]

```
package ej2;

public class PrincipalCod {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static int cont = 0;

public static String visitNode(EDBinaryTree<Character> ab, char car, String decode) {

    cont++;
    System.out.println("Cont: "+cont);

    if(ab.getLeftSubTree() != null) {
        visitNode(ab.getLeftSubTree(), car, decode+"0");
    }
    if(ab.getRightSubTree() != null) {
        visitNode(ab.getRightSubTree(), car, decode+"1");
    }
    if(ab.getLeftSubTree() == null && ab.getRightSubTree() == null) {
        //OMG! leaf!
        if(ab.root.data.equals(car)){
            return decode;
        }else{
            decode="";
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static String codificar(EDBinaryTree<Character> ab, char car){
    return visitNode(ab, car, "");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char caracter = 'f';
    EDBinaryTree<Character> ab = new EDBinaryTree<Character>();
    //i create leaf nodes
    EDBinaryTree<Character> a = new EDBinaryTree<Character>('a');
    EDBinaryTree<Character> f = new EDBinaryTree<Character>('f');
    EDBinaryTree<Character> b = new EDBinaryTree<Character>('b');
    EDBinaryTree<Character> c = new EDBinaryTree<Character>('c');

    EDBinaryTree<Character> sonrightleft = new EDBinaryTree<Character>(null, f, b);
    EDBinaryTree<Character> sonright = new EDBinaryTree<Character>(null, hijoderizq, c);
    ab = new EDBinaryTree<Character>(null, a, hijoder);
    System.out.println("-----Tree used--------");
    ab.displayTree();
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    String cod = codificar(ab, caracter);
    System.out.println("Solution: "+cod);
}

}
```

Any idea?

Testing it in Eclipse, it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ej2.PrincipalCod.visitNode(PrincipalCod.java:23)
at ej2.PrincipalCod.visitNode(PrincipalCod.java:16)
at ej2.PrincipalCod.visitNode(PrincipalCod.java:16)
at ej2.PrincipalCod.codificar(PrincipalCod.java:33)
at ej2.PrincipalCod.main(PrincipalCod.java:50)
```

It crashes in the line: "if(ab.root.data.equals(car)){"

Comment: Im not sure where the NPE comes from yet, but it seems like your code will always visit a left node, even if it should visit right. All you do is check for null, you dont actually check if its the right node. Also you should do println(decode) in visitNode before the ifs and post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ab = new EDBinaryTree<Character>(null, a, hijoder);
```

I'm guessing this creates a node with `null` data

Since `data == null`, then

```
    if(ab.root.data.equals(car))
```

will fail

Comment: If I add this:       if(ab.root.data != null && ab.root.data.equals(car)) it also fails.

Comment: Then debug it to identify what exactly is null. I'm guessing it's root, which means you're not creating your tree correctly, or your EDBinaryTree class has a bug.